# JQuery button is not triggering service call via ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have a JSON service and i am trying to execute this service via ajax call through jquery in webpage. When i have created button and trying to execute click event but i am not able to get any alert message as well as service call also not triggering that means click event itself is not firing at all . please help!

below is code

```
 <title></title>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { });
        $('#buttonnew').click(function () {
            alert("Hi");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'service2.svc/GetRestriction',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: ({ property: '99883', code: 1 }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (DATA) {
                    alert("hi");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery reference?

Comment: lots of errors 1. jquery not included.. 2. doc ready is blank. 3. click is outside of doc ready.

Comment: have you tried to put the code that assigns the click event inside the "ready" function? like this:
$(document).ready(function () {   $('#buttonnew').click .......... });

Comment: I wanted to add the jquery 1.11.2- js file but i didn't get files so i download contain and added to new file 'Javascript.js' which is i already added here in src. That is the reason i am getting $ as selector after adding this file to src.

Comment: Ricardo are you talking about this line    $(document).ready(function () { });
        $('#buttonnew').click(function () {
            alert("hi");
            $.ajax({

Comment: I am using this code inside .aspx where i have button so i don't have any html page for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only error you have in your code is that you are asigning tht click event on the button before document is ready. So you can just Try this :

```
 <title></title>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
           $('#buttonnew').click(function () {
            alert("Hi");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'service2.svc/GetRestriction',
                method: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: ({ property: '99883', code: 1 }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (DATA) {
                    alert("hi");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
```

I've tested it with Jquery 2.2.2.

I hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks Ariel for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to wire up the click event when the DOM has been loaded.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

         $('#buttonnew').click(function () {
                alert("Hi");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'service2.svc/GetRestriction',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: ({ property: '99883', code: 1 }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (DATA) {
                        alert("hi");
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            });    
    });
```

Comment: Thanks ritesh , actually new to this Ajax so i missed this point!